# How to avoid inferring empty array

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I have typescript code as follows:

```js
function loader<P extends [], T>(load: (...args: P) => Promise<T>, lazy = false) {
    const result: { value?: T, error?: unknown } = {}
    function start(...args: P) {
        load(...args)
            .then(v => result.value = v)
            .catch(e => result.error = e)
    }

    // Argument of type '[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'P'.
    if (!lazy) start()

    return { restart: start, result }
}

const load = (a = 1, b = 2) => Promise.resolve(a + b)

// restart is () => void
const { restart, result } = loader(load)
```

I need to limit the parameter `load` so that it can be called without parameters, that is, it has no parameters or all parameters are optional. And same to function `start`.

Moreover, I hope `restart` and `load` have the same parameter list. That is, `restart` should be `(a?: number, b?: number) => Promise<number>`.

Comment: *"...I expected it to be `[a?: number | undefined, b?: number | undefined]`"* FWIW, I can get it to infer `(number | undefined)[]` by changing what `P` means. That's fairly close to the tuple type you were expecting (but not quite the same): https://tsplay.dev/NB1Ldw

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I wish this function could be more general, that is, it can receive any load function, as long as all its parameters are optional. Such as `load: (a = 1, b = 'str', c = { k: 'value' }) => Promise`

Comment: Can you demonstrate why you need `P` at all? I can get the behavior you're asking for without it, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3KRLm). If you have a use case that requires `P`, please [edit] the code in the question to show it, so that any suggestions we make for refactoring will satisfy that use case.

Comment: Thanks. So the problem here is that TS doesn't support *lower bound* constraints as requested at [ms/TS#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520). You'd *like* to say `P super [] extends any[]` or maybe `[] extends P extends any[]`, but this is not directly supported. There are workarounds with conditional types or other tricks, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NaLOow). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function types are [contravariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Function_types) in their parameter types, meaning that if `X extends Y` then `((a: Y) => void) extends ((a: X) => void)` and not vice versa.  This is sometimes surprising to people, but it makes sense when you think about the expectations of the receiver of data. My beagle Snoopy is a dog, but a kennel that only accepts beagles named Snoopy wouldn't really be a "dog kennel".  The more freedom function callers have, the less freedom the function implementer has, and vice versa.

So, if you're looking for "any function that accepts no arguments", you are not trying to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) the parameter list `P` such that `P extends []`.  That constraint is exactly backwards.  You really want `[] extends P`.  That is, you want `[]` to be a *lower bound* on `P`, not an *upper bound*.  The upper bound on `P` is just `any[]`.

But unfortunately TypeScript does not natively support lower bound generics. There is a longstanding open issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#14520](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14520) asking for that.  Maybe someday that will be supported, and you can write `<P super [] extends any[]>` or maybe `<[] extends P extends any[]>`, but for now there's no direct support for it.

You'll have to work around it.

---

One workaround is to just give `P` an upper bound of `any[]` and then use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to accept or reject a call depending on whether or not `[] extends P`:

```
function loader<P extends any[], T>(
    load: [] extends P ? (...args: P) => Promise<T> : never, lazy = false) {
    const result: { value?: T, error?: unknown } = {}
    function start(...args: P) {
        load(...args)
            .then(v => result.value = v)
            .catch(e => result.error = e)
    }
    if (!lazy) (start as () => void)() // need an assertion here
    return { restart: start, result }
}
```

Note that the [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) `start as () => void` is necessary because even though the conditional type should enforce things from the callers' end, the compiler's not smart enough to evaluate it inside the [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function.

Anyway, let's test it:

```
const load = (a = 1, b = 2) => Promise.resolve(a + b)
const { restart, result } = loader(load); // okay
// const restart: (a?: number, b?: number) => void

const badLoad = (a = 1, b: number) => Promise.resolve(a + b);
loader(badLoad); // error
```

Looks good. The compiler allows `loader(load)` but rejects `loader(badLoad)`.

---

Another possible workaround here is just to infer `P` from the input function, but make sure that the function parameter list is assignable to `Partial<P>`, using [the `Partial` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype) to convert the parameter list to one with all [optional elements](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types):

```
function loader<P extends any[], T>(load: (...args: Partial<P>) => Promise<T>, lazy = false) {
  // ✂ ⋯ same impl as above ⋯ ✂ // 
}

const load = (a = 1, b = 2) => Promise.resolve(a + b)
const { restart, result } = loader(load)
// const restart: (a?: number, b?: number) => void
const badLoad = (a = 1, b: number) => Promise.resolve(a + b);
loader(badLoad); // error
```

Also looks good.  You still can't do much inside the implementation to avoid the type assertion here either. The compiler's just not willing to let you call `start()` without explicitly telling it that `start` allows that. Maybe if lower bound constraints are ever natively supported, then the compiler will be able to verify the safety of such calls automatically.  For now, though, this is the best I can do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB1AjEg3gWAFBIKQDMBXYeAFwEsB7YJAGxpABMIAnAHgAUkIAPChGAsoSEMACeAbQC6AGiQAVAHwAKPIS2NmLAFxI5fQcNFJeAfiRqAdHZDsA5lAPcAlEgC8K8+xpgqKAhOVSQDYAgANw5FBhAAL0kvYhAGII8cfG0CeDooCiR2aBIGCgNMJEjUkggLAyVFDj92OqQyAGtgGgB3egBfZMw+zWziMkpaenyHClt7JxdzDJHRwiZWOZsHZzcV1e0bCgALYTVIrx8iqBKKGyqGGuTI3az9g-gQCngjtWRvQuKpRsTRo7GSEBeq2Gr20VCI1gAhHFEh41NN2AUQGI1B5-pEaFQWG4cUgAPSkpARCAscT0LFBDGTJAnIp7LRFCgkdj0CpXCgzAzoiiKK43JDQrTQva5YD5HSsZJqEDJNCKABGyQATLifNw-AEgjYrjQGNElUgANRINWQwgyuW86D8jEiwEFAaeeVsdhqdZEgDcZIpNHaIEke3JSHtBT5AusIFawBIYDVMWtieTqfYOsqBJYeGleQKatYABldIrlZ7VdbwpmODm9f5AhAjdATWblVabf69n6OGoSyxy6w3IHIyD2HgpbhQJBYAhkChNVg9qRyNQ6F6ODxjEIRGIJDIFMp1H6DJttotuDMqKkeCpG-qWyEVLEEklPURUulVzCtNGALXKU5SVNUtT1I07DNK0HRdL04qDBKozrhMW5CpeCyuMs-6jH6mE7GybxIIcJzAGcFxATcdzgU8trEYQNgfF8Px-JcbrAtBoLgvR2jIdkcKIsikiokK4jYjm+KEsSHiRlSNISOJDKbvQLIQERBAclyPJAc6ZRIEKrrAe6ewzgBRZepWKrqlqT7NoaxqmhA5rdrxgGOoZVGlIhnr9j6fq8ZGgGxhiF4JnWKZpmqGaRdmlFSfmMKAUOI40p65rVuqEVZnZBqto5naWtaY59roA4pboY5BnwXFTrgfRAA)

Comment: Very detailed answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider following code:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3];
const b: [] = a;
```

You can see the error message below:

```
Type 'number[]' is not assignable to type '[]'.
  Target allows only 0 element(s) but source may have more.
```

Actually, `[a?: number | undefined, b?: number | undefined]` not extends `[]`.

Instead of `<P extends [], T>`, use `<P extends any[], T>` to solve this issue.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwhylBgEYAeABXhAA8MRVgBneAbQF0AaeAFQD4AFIWIAueIIB002AHNm4ygEp4AXn7xKMHAFsszEOQFLxGAJ4AHEDkQEiwANwBYAFChIsBCnTY8d4iAwAExUNPSMLPBQqGacPALC9uJSMjDyiirqmtp6Bkb8JvDmVjb+jq6uYHjMGGVqElD1pDwARvVBmRpauvogknDMOBAAbiCCjQDU8C1KFS4A9PPwAJKoiIFFABZQtdT67ByuIiSkicRKgs3wHc4urosraxsY27vw+2xQAPziqMg6LQ2AB94GhQIgsKgQMBWj94H8AcDQUwQBCocBDi5joEgmdgBcrjdXEA)